# Con statement not working in Raster Calculator of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, map-algebra, conditional

I'm trying to combine two rasters in 10.3 using a con statement with the raster calculator in map algebra.  (ie - con (raster 1 ==1, raster 1, raster 2))
where raster 1 is a smaller extent and does not have continuous values, and raster 2 is a land use raster.
the output is always equivalent to raster 1 only.  i've tried the CON tool, the "plus" tool instead of raster calculator (raster 1 + raster 2; so that i can then reclassify).  with the "plus" tool, i get the combined values, but the values for raster 2 where there should be NoData for raster 1 are missing.

this is a simple process i've done many times with prior versions, so what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure both have the same extents (or at least an extent that covers both datasets). try something like:

1. `Con(IsNull(Raster1) & ~IsNull(Raster2),-1,Raster1)` <- this should
   give you a raster 1 with all areas of no data turned to -1 with the
   extent expanded to include raster 2. You can change the `true`statement into any number you
   like make sure you don't have the same value within the Raster1 that
   is why I chose a negative number.Let's say you named the above
   as Raster3.
2. Then you can do your `Con(raster3 ==1, raster 3, raster 2)`